# Method for downloading file from SharePoint doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have written a method that  reads excel files from a certain folder in SharePoint and saves them in Desktop. This is my code , but it doesn't work because I don't see the file anywhere in the Desktop of my computer.

The connection with SharePoint is made in another method.

```
private static void transferFile(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder fold, 
ClientContext ctx,string targetPath, ref StringBuilder str, ref bool errors)
    {
        str.AppendLine("Folder " + fold.Name);
        ctx.Load(fold.Files, f1 => f1.Include(f2 => f2.Name, f2 => f2.ListItemAllFields));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in fold.Files)
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> fieldsVal = file.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues;


            string extension = file.Name.Substring(file.Name.Length - 4);
            try
            {
                if (extension == "xlsx")
                {

                    string sourceUrl = "https://mysharepoint.com" + fieldsVal["FileRef"].ToString();

                    int size = int.Parse(fieldsVal[System.Xml.XmlConvert.EncodeName("File Size")].ToString());

                    try
                    {
                        int length = 0;
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        int chunkSize = 32 * 1024;
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];

                        FileInformation ffl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, fieldsVal["FileRef"].ToString());
                        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        while ((bytesRead = ffl.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            length += bytesRead;
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }

                        Stream streamFile = null;
                        string fileName;

                        streamFile = stream;
                        fileName = file.Name;

    var newFileName = Path.Combine(targetPath,fileName);
    var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(newFileName);

     ffl.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
    catch{
    }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting if any? What is the issue ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors

Comment: You're not getting errors because you're swallowing the exceptions in your empty catch blocks.

Comment: It was a null reference exception, I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the file from SharePoint online to your local system using following code

```
internal static void DownloadFilesFromSharePoint(string siteUrl, string folderPath, string tempLocation)
{
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
    ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, Password);

    FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath).Files;

    ctx.Load(files);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach(File file in files)
    {
        FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        var filePath = tempLocation + file.Name;
        using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `folderPath` is a SharePoint folder relative path (e.g.: \site\libraryname\folder).

You can add your condition to check your file is `.xlsx` in `foreach` loop as follows

```
foreach(File file in files)
{
    if(file.Name.Contains(".xlsx")) {

        FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
        ......
    }
}
```